# c# Unity: Trying to make a biome generation algorithm multithreadable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voronoi

I'm currently learning how to code games and have designed a biom generation algorithm.

As long as I run that algorithm below syncron, it generates the same output every time and works perfectly fine.

Now I tried to speed it up and make it multithreaded, but every time I call the method, it results in a different result.

As far as I know, I used Threadsave Collections, whenever necessary, but it still doesn't work.

Also, I tried to lock the collection, but this didn't work either.

So I'm completely clueless as to why this doesn't work.

If you see anything that I could make better or how I could fix that problem, please let me know.

This code is working:

```
 private Biome[,] Generate(string worldSeed, Vector2Int targetChunk, List<(Biome, float)> multiplier, float centroidsPerChunk)
{
    //Calculate the NeighboursToGenerate depeding on the cendroids per Chunk value
    int chunkNeighboursToGenerate = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(1f / centroidsPerChunk * 12.5f));
    int chunkSize = 8;

    //Create List that contains all centroids of the chunk
    List<(Vector2Int, Biome)> centroids = new();

    //Create Centdroids for every chunk of the generated region around the targetchunk
    for (int chunkX = targetChunk.x - chunkNeighboursToGenerate; chunkX < targetChunk.x + chunkNeighboursToGenerate + 1; chunkX++)
    {
        for (int chunkZ = targetChunk.y - chunkNeighboursToGenerate; chunkZ < targetChunk.y + chunkNeighboursToGenerate + 1; chunkZ++)
        {
            List<(Vector2Int, Biome)> generatedCentdroids = GetCentdroidsByChunk(worldSeed, new(chunkX, chunkZ), centroidsPerChunk, chunkSize, multiplier, targetChunk, chunkNeighboursToGenerate);
            foreach ((Vector2Int, Biome) generatedCentdroid in generatedCentdroids)
            {
                centroids.Add(generatedCentdroid);
            }
        }
    }
    Biome[,] biomeMap = new Biome[chunkSize, chunkSize];


    //---Generate biomeMap of the target Chunk---
    for (int tx = 0; tx < chunkSize; tx++)
    {
        for (int tz = 0; tz < chunkSize; tz++)
        {
            int x = chunkSize * chunkNeighboursToGenerate + tx;
            int z = chunkSize * chunkNeighboursToGenerate + tz;
            biomeMap[tz, tx] = GetClosestCentroidBiome(new(x, z), centroids.ToArray());
        };
    };

    //Return the biome map of the target chunk
    return biomeMap;
}
private static List<(Vector2Int, Biome)> GetCentdroidsByChunk(string worldSeed, Vector2Int chunkToGenerate, float centroidsPerChunk, int chunkSize, List<(Biome, float)> multiplier, Vector2Int targetChunk, int chunkNeighboursToGenerate)
{
    List<(Vector2Int, Biome)> centroids = new();

    //---Generate Cendroids of a single chunk---
    float centroidsInThisChunk = centroidsPerChunk;

    //Init randomizer
    System.Random randomInstance = new(Randomizer.GetSeed(worldSeed, chunkToGenerate.x, chunkToGenerate.y));

    while (centroidsInThisChunk > 0.0f)
    {
        //if at least one more centroid is to generate do it
        //if not randomize by the given probability if another one should be generated
        if (centroidsInThisChunk >= 1 || (float)randomInstance.NextDouble() * (1 - 0) + 0 <= centroidsInThisChunk)
        {
            //Generate random point for a new centroid
            Vector2Int pos = new(randomInstance.Next(0, chunkSize + 1), randomInstance.Next(0, chunkSize + 1));

            //map the point to a zerobased coordinatesystem
            int mappedX = (((chunkToGenerate.x - targetChunk.x) + chunkNeighboursToGenerate) * chunkSize) + pos.x;
            int mappedZ = (((chunkToGenerate.y - targetChunk.y) + chunkNeighboursToGenerate) * chunkSize) + pos.y;
            Vector2Int mappedPos = new Vector2Int(mappedX, mappedZ);

            //Select the biom randomized
            Biome biome = Randomizer.GetRandomBiom(randomInstance, multiplier);
            centroids.Add(new(mappedPos, biome));
            centroidsInThisChunk -= 1.0f;
        }
        //if no centroid is left to generate, end the loop
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return centroids;
}

//Calculates the closest Centroid to the given possition
Biome GetClosestCentroidBiome(Vector2Int pixelPos, IEnumerable<(Vector2Int, Biome)> centroids)
{
    //Warp the possition so the biom borders won't be straight
    //Vector2 warpedPos = pixelPos + Get2DTurbulence(pixelPos);
    Vector2 warpedPos = pixelPos;

    float smallestDst = float.MaxValue;
    Biome closestBiome = Biome.Empty;
    foreach ((Vector2Int, Biome) centroid in centroids)
    {
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(warpedPos, centroid.Item1);
        if (distance < smallestDst)
        {
            smallestDst = distance;
            closestBiome = centroid.Item2;
        }
    }
    return closestBiome;
}
public static class Randomizer
{
    //Generates a random integerseed by combining an hashing the inputvalues
    public static int GetSeed(string worldSeed, int chunkx, int chunkz)
    {
        var stringSeed = worldSeed + ":" + chunkx + ";" + chunkz;
        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
        byte[] hashed = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringSeed));
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(hashed, 0);
    }

    //Returns a random biome based on the given properbilities/multiplier
    //multiplier = 2 for example means the biom is generated twice as often as usually
    public static Biome GetRandomBiom(System.Random rndm, List<(Biome, float)> multiplier)
    {
        float multmax = 0.0f;
        multiplier.ForEach(x => multmax += x.Item2);
        //Generate a random value that is in the range of all multiplieres added
        float biome = (float)rndm.NextDouble() * (multmax + 0.01f);

        //Map the biome to the multipliers and return the biome
        float multcalc = 0.0f;
        for (int r = 0; r < multiplier.Count; r++)
        {
            multcalc += multiplier[r].Item2;
            if (multcalc >= biome)
            {
                return multiplier[r].Item1;
            }
        }
        //Return Biome.Empty if something did't worked correct
        return Biome.Empty;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
    private Biome[,] Generate(string worldSeed, Vector2Int targetChunk, List<(Biome, float)> multiplier, float centroidsPerChunk)
{
    //Calculate the NeighboursToGenerate depeding on the cendroids per Chunk value
    int chunkNeighboursToGenerate = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(1f / centroidsPerChunk * 12.5f));
    int chunkSize = 8;

    //Create List that contains all centroids of the chunk
    ConcurrentBag<(Vector2Int, Biome)> centroids = new();

    ConcurrentQueue<Task> tasks = new();
    //Create Centdroids for every chunk of the generated region around the targetchunk
    for (int chunkX = targetChunk.x - chunkNeighboursToGenerate; chunkX < targetChunk.x + chunkNeighboursToGenerate + 1; chunkX++)
    {
        for (int chunkZ = targetChunk.y - chunkNeighboursToGenerate; chunkZ < targetChunk.y + chunkNeighboursToGenerate + 1; chunkZ++)
        {
            tasks.Enqueue(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                List<(Vector2Int, Biome)> generatedCentdroids = GetCentdroidsByChunk(worldSeed, new(chunkX, chunkZ), centroidsPerChunk, chunkSize, multiplier, targetChunk, chunkNeighboursToGenerate);
                foreach ((Vector2Int, Biome) generatedCentdroid in generatedCentdroids)
                {
                    centroids.Add(generatedCentdroid);
                }
            }));
        }
    }
    Biome[,] biomeMap = new Biome[chunkSize, chunkSize];

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    //---Generate biomeMap of the target Chunk---
    for (int tx = 0; tx < chunkSize; tx++)
    {
        for (int tz = 0; tz < chunkSize; tz++)
        {
            int x = chunkSize * chunkNeighboursToGenerate + tx;
            int z = chunkSize * chunkNeighboursToGenerate + tz;
            biomeMap[tz, tx] = GetClosestCentroidBiome(new(x, z), centroids.ToArray());
        };
    };

    //Return the biome map of the target chunk
    return biomeMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're starting to get into programming and you want to learn multi-threading, converting a large piece of complex code like this is not where you want to start. I highly recommend you pick up a book or tutorial on threading/async in C#/.NET before starting something like this. Unity also has its own multi-threading library with its Job System, which is built for the Unity workflow: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystemMultithreading.html

I don't think most people could find what's causing the problem in these two code snippets alone. But I have a couple of suggestions

- Change your tasks collection to a `List<T>`, `tasks` is only ever accessed on one thread so there's no need to use `ConcurrentQueue<T>`
- Is `Biome` a class? Cause if so it's *technically* fine but modifying data structures from multiple threads gets hairy fast. And while I can't *see* that you're modifying data from these snippets, without the full code I can't say for sure. Turn `Biome` into a struct or make a struct equivalent for threading purposes.
- Also avoid calling `centroids.ToArray()` in your loop, as doing so will actually copy the original array over and over and over again. Call it once outside of your loop and that alone should be a pretty huge performance bump.
- Just find a full-blown tutorial for threading/async/Unity's Job system (depending on which you'd rather learn for your use case) and start from there, I can tell from your use of the concurrent libraries and `List<T>` inside your tasks that you're new to threading. Understanding what code is ran on another thread and the repercussions from that (race conditions, and so on) is huge.

Comment: Thank you. Biome is a Enum. I now started to learn how the unityjobsystem works and I'm trying to implement my worldgeneration using that system. Thank you for the hint, it is verry useful.